# Nginx - How to serve 404 and static files through private networking?

Tags: nginx, node.js

I've followed this tutorial exactly to set up, successfully my Node.Js app: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

My Node app lives on a separate droplet, as does my Nginx.
I'm redirecting all my www and http traffic to https://domain.com. This all WORKS.

Now I also want to serve custom error files. But they are located in the node app on the other droplet, in the public folder /var/www/app/public. Is there anyway I can serve my 404 file from Nginx, but keep it on the Node.JS droplet?

Same question for my static files (images/fonts), is there a way I can serve my static files from Nginx, but keep them on my Node.js droplet (NOT copy them over to Nginx droplet?)

Thanks

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://ip_of_node_droplet:4000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to my mind:

- You could setup a service like [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) on the droplet hosting the files (*server 1*) in question. After this, export the directory containing the files (via NFS) and mount it on your machine hosting `nginx` (*server 2*).
- You could set up `nginx` as well on your *server 1*,.

To make this work, you would have to alter your `nginx` config on *server 2*. Include location directives for your static files and error pages; maybe something along the lines of:

```
location /static {
  root /srv/nfs-imported;
}

error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
location = /custom_404.html {
  root /srv/nfs-imported;
  internal;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
location = /custom_50x.html {
  root /srv/nfs-imported;
  internal;
}
```

This is just an example, and assumes, you're going for my first outlined idea. In case you're more interested in the second proposal, you wouldn't use `root` directives, but instead `proxy_pass`, like you're using already for all requests which should go to your `node app`.